# How to use Vestris API to power on ESX Server Virtual Machines using VM Name Only?

Tags: c#, virtual-machine, vmware, esxi

I'm using the Vestris.VMWareLib API to remotely control my VMs on an ESX 5.0 server. I use the VMWareVirtualMachine.Open method to power on my virtual images. My code is written in C#. The problem is that you need to know the path to the datastore before you can power on the image, which is a bit of a pain.
Is there a way to power on images using just the VM name?
Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the same technology to power on the VMs, and we have a database with the VM names. And we have a naming convenction, the VM name must unique (do not contains any other server name! f.e: abc and abcd is not allowed).

And inside the code I use the following linq to search for the actual VM by name:

```
List<VMWareVirtualMachine> vitualMachines = virtualHost.RegisteredVirtualMachines.ToList();
VMWareVirtualMachine serverTofind = vitualMachines.Where(vm => vm.PathName.Contains("Your server name")).First();
```

I hope it hepls!

Comment: Fantastic, works great. Thanks for a short but useful solution.

Comment: Actually, after looking at it, this isn't what I needed. Your code finds the right machine is the name is in the path - but what if it isn't? From looking at all the options, the GetProperty method may be the best way to get the VM name but I don't know how to use it. Any ideas?